# Экранирование символов в ini файле

Tags: php, функции, ini

Есть функция которая считывает текст по коду с ini файл:

```
public function alert ($name) {
    $this->data = parse_ini_file($this->directory.'alert.ini');
    return $this->data[$name];
}
```

Содержимое ini файла:

```
0001 = danger
0002 = online
0003 = offline
0004 = checked="checked"
```

Чтение и вывод происходит так:

```
echo $text->alert('0004');
```

Проблема:

Как можете заметить в четвертой строке ini файла есть кавычки и тире.
При ее вызове выдает ошибку:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=' in
```

Задача:

Можно ли как это экранировать такие символы или обработать функцией?

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: поделитесь пожалуйста кодом функции parse_ini_file

Comment: Я же написал функцию в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

> *Можно ли как это экранировать такие символы или обработать функцией?*

Примечание из [оф.документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php):

> `Если значение в ini-файле содержит прочие символы, кроме букв и цифр, оно должно заключаться в двойные кавычки (").`

Исходя из этого, можно дописать метод-обработчик, который будет предварительно читать ini-файл, проверять символы и перезаписывать. См. пример:

```
class Foo
{
    private $ini;
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct(string $filename = 'alert.ini')
    {
        $this->ini = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
        $this->escape_characters_ini_file();
    }

    private function escape_characters_ini_file()
    {
        file_put_contents($this->ini, join(PHP_EOL, array_map(function($i){
            [$name, $value] = explode(' = ', $i, 2);
            return $name . ' = ' . preg_replace('~(?<!")[^\pL\d\s"]~', '"$0"', $value);
        }, file($this->ini, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES))));
    }

    public function alert($name)
    {
        $this->data = parse_ini_file($this->ini);
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
}

$text = new Foo();
echo $text->alert('0004');
```

---

**Или используйте вместо *parse_ini_file()* другую функцию для чтения файла.**